# Use Current Month to Get Sheet Name

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a series of sheets named: JAN 2022, FEB 2022, etc.
I have a cell that is pulling E2 from the sheet as ='JAN 2022'!E2

I want to pull the E2 value for the current month. I tried using the following, but it doesn't work:
='(CONCATENATE(TEXT(today(),"mmmm")," ",2022)'!E2

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
=INDIRECT(text(today(),"mmm "&2022)&"!E2")
```

Answer (score 0):

try: `=indirect(upper(text(today(),"mmm yyyy"))&"!E2")`